# Find Unique Value based on criteria

Tags: unique, sql-server-2019

Hello… I am trying to figure out how to look under ModelName column, which could contain duplicate values and see if ReleaseType column for that same model contains “Final Release.” If yes, do nothing, if not Return Unique ModelName (perhaps based on the latest Date). Fields in Green are the one I am trying to show and the one in red should not be visible:
[image]

Is this something that could be done in SQL Server 2019?
Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Model](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ModelName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FormFactorID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Revision] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [SVID] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [SSID] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [Picture] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [NVME] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [ReleaseStatusID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Model__3214EC27B0574C2B] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReleaseType](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ReleaseType] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__ReleaseT__3214EC27CD0730DB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductRelease](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ReleaseTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [ModelID] [int] NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
    [ECO] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](800) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__ProductR__3214EC27CE911F54] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

ID from ReleaseType table joined with ReleaseTypeID from ProductRelease table

ID from Model table joined with ModelID from ProductRelease table

Here is my Query so far:

```
SELECT
    dbo.Model.ModelName, 
    dbo.ReleaseType.ReleaseType, 
    dbo.ProductRelease.ECO, 
    dbo.ProductRelease.Date

FROM            
    dbo.Model 
        INNER JOIN dbo.ProductRelease ON dbo.Model.ID = dbo.ProductRelease.ModelID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.ReleaseType ON dbo.ProductRelease.ReleaseTypeID = dbo.ReleaseType.ID

ORDER BY 
    dbo.Model.ModelName, 
    dbo.ProductRelease.Date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it doable for instance with  windowed fucntions:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT m.ModelName, 
     rt.ReleaseType, 
     pr.ECO, 
     pr.Date,
     cnt = COUNT(CASE WHEN rt.ReleaseType='Final Release' THEN 1 END) 
           OVER(PARTITION BY m.ModelName),
     rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.ModelName ORDER BY pr.Date DESC)
   FROM dbo.Model m
   JOIN dbo.ProductRelease pr
     ON m.ID = pr.ModelID 
   JOIN dbo.ReleaseType rt
     ON pr.ReleaseTypeID = rt.ID
)
SELECT ModelName, ReleaseType, ECO, Date
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 0   -- exclude groups with 'Final Release'
  AND rn = 1    -- get only newest occurence per ModelName
ORDER BY ModelName;
```

Comment: Thank you for the info... It looks like there is an error: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'cnt'.

Comment: Awesome... Thank you very much for your help :-)